# Movie about family that moves to a ranch to keep horses, and there's a lady ghost searching for "Ian"

Tags: story-identification, movie, ghost

In 1999/2000 I recorded a movie on VHS that I watched often and even showed my friends but later lost the tape.

In the opening credits a boy drowns in a pond in the 1800's.

Then in the 1990's a family moves in a ranch and keep horses. A couple and their young adult daughter. Every night a ghost, this 1800's lady, bangs on doors searching for "Ian".

Then there's this little romance- thing between the daughter and a farm hand and some galloping in the woods seeing ghosts.

In the end the mother finds Ian and the ghosts are united.

Has anyone seen this movie? I'd otherwise doubt my own memory, that maybe it never was, but my friends remember it too.

Comment: A Haunting in Connecticut (2002)? Made for TV movie. Buried Secrets (1996)? Do you remember more details? Actors or something?

Comment: Take a look at [The Blue Boy](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109304/?ref_=ttpl_ov), it has some partial match: "Marie is told the story of a young boy who drowned in a nearby lake long ago"

Comment: Welcome! Please note that "What was this movie" is not a descriptive question title. Basically, if it's not good enough for a google search, it's not good enough here. Would you start your google search by typing "what was this movie"?

Comment: Actually I did just that when trying to search for finding lost movies in Google.

Comment: Buried secrets or The blue boy were not a match. I don't remember any actors, but I think the movie was made in 1998